# How to verify checkbox if it is an ImageView

Tags: android, ruby, android-imageview, calabash-android

I am using ruby 2.0 and in my app i have a checkbox which is in the class of ImageView and all the properties to verify check box like "checked" or "selected" is not enabled.

Now in this state how to verify the check box is checked or not?[image: Elements of Check box]

Answer (score 1):

You can call any public method on a view matched by a query by adding it to the end of the method. To see if a view is checked you can use `query("...", :checked)`. Calabash recognises this as a 'PropertyOperation' and looks for the methods `isChecked`, `getChecked`, and `hasChecked`. `query("...", :checked)` and `query("...", :isChecked)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 ways to do this:

- Create a 'CheckableImageView', like [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/photup/blob/master/client/src/uk/co/senab/photup/views/CheckableImageView.java), which allows your ImageView to have `checked` state, and you can use that in your Calabash test
- Or use `contentDescription`, this is more like a trick. In your Android implementation, update `contentDescription` to say 'checked' or 'unchecked' when state changes. Then verify `contentDescription` attribute in your Calabash test

Personally I prefer the first approach, it's cleaner, and also makes more sense since you are trying to represent a checkable item by using a non-checkable `ImageView`.